# Spark driver side running exceed memory after long time running

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I get a simple spark application. What bother me is that after running for around 10 hours, the driver get error that having 3GB memory, but actually use 4.7GB.
My logic is quite simple:
First get all file paths and store them into a `Seq` named `allpath`.
Next, `allpath.map(path => upsert(getStatistics(path))`. `getStatistics` function works to count the record numbers of files under that path, which looks like:

```
val parquetDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("/path/to/parquet/files")
parquetDF.register("tmp_table")
resDF.sqlContext.sql("select count(*) record_num from tmp_table").withColumn(...).withColumn(...)
```

`upsert` function aim to do `insert ... on duplicate key...` operation on a target table in mysql database by partition:

```
val sql = """insert into table ...... on duplicate key id = id"""
currentDF.foreachPartition(iter => {
val state = create statement
while(iter.hasNext) {
val row = iter.next()
state.addBatch(sql.format(...))
}
state.executeBatch()
})
```

Basically, I can't find too much thing need use driver side memory in storing in the total procedure. Is that any other reason that cause the usage of too much driver side memory? Any suggestion welcome.

ps:
spark submit configuration:

```
  --driver-memory 2g --executor-cores 2
--driver-java-options="-XX:+UseG1GC"
--executor-memory 6g --num-executors 8
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1000 --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=1000
```

Comment: why driver side why not cluster side? executing driver side is in-efficient.

Comment: @RamPrasadG Actually, I am running on cluster mode. I just don't know why my driver side memory usage is so high.

Comment: paste complete logic here pls!

Comment: sorry I misunderstood. The way you are upserting with foreachpartition is correct.